# Difference between Surface 2 and Surface Pro 2

Tags: microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro

Can anybody explain the difference between the Microsoft Surface 2 and the Surface Pro 2 in terms of hardware and software features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arm (Windows RT - a handicapped windows that only allows app store apps.) vs Intel (Windows 8.x - it's windows... So whatever can go on a normal computer can go on here, also has access to the store).

Battery consumption, ram, performance. Just look up the specs sheets side by side.

Comment: avoid surface. Buy surface pro 2 instead.

Comment: At this point I'd actually get the more recent version (at least a 3, but preferably a 4) as they fixed the aspect ratio, among other various improvements.

Comment: I can get used surface pro 2 for $400 :) And I rarely use laptop because I have nice desktop. But yea, thanks.